# What happens to properties on a constructor function?

Tags: javascript

Suppose there is:

```
function someConstructor(){
   // initialize
}
someConstructor.prop = {test:'test'};

var obj1 = new someConstructor();
var obj2 = new someConstructor();
```

My guess would be that there is still only one copy of `prop` available via `someConstructor.prop` for `obj1` and `obj2` available via someConstructor.

Comment: Properties on functions have nothing to do with inheritance. In fact functions themselves have very little to do with inheritance... except for initializing the prototypal relationship.

Comment: I would highly recommend John Resig's [Learning App](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/) for Advanced Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prototype is used to make sure that 1 and only 1 object is there for all instances. However those instances may override that prototype with their own objects. In firefox at least, setting `Test.opts` does not allow `o1` or `o2` to inherit it. But setting `Test.prototype.opts` does.

Try the following:

```
var Test = function () {};
Test.opts = {helo: "hello"};

var o1 = new Test();
var o2 = new Test();
console.log( o1.opts ); // undefined
o1.opts = {helo: "bye"};
console.log( o2.opts ); // undefined

Test.prototype.opts = {helo: "hello"};
console.log( o1.opts ); // Object { helo: "bye" }
console.log( o2.opts ); // Object { helo: "hello" }
```

Comment: Very concise and accurate answer.

Comment: @pure_code.com: Do you have a point you're trying to make with that example?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> function SomeConstructor(){}; someConstructor.prop = …
> ```

JavaScript is case sensitive, this is example won't work.

> My guess would be that there is still only one copy of prop for obj1 and obj2.

No. There won't be any copies at all. `prop` is a property of the function object, and has nothing to do with `obj1` or `obj2`. It is not inherited by them.

And that's the difference to using a property on the prototype, which is the object from which `obj1` and `obj2` do inherit.

> a static property that is copied directly to the object

Only if by "object" you mean the constructor function here. In JS, [there are no classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418669/javascript-do-i-need-to-put-this-var-for-every-variable-in-an-object/13418980#13418980), and no "static" properties. Yet, the correspondent of "static class attributes" would be properties on the constructor function.